# gwt - DataGrid won't show all data inside, even having scroll

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in an `AbsolutePanel`.

I set it size via `myDataGrid.setSize("100px", "231px");`

It is supposed to show 140 data items, but it only shows like 60 or something like that, with automatic vertical scroll bar presented.

But why it shows only part of the data, not full set?

Comment: I know this might sound obvious but did you add a pager (SimplePager) ?

Comment: Most probably you do not specify page size in DataGrid constructor. Can you post DataGrid init code?

Comment: It's not clear what the size in pixels has to do with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use a default constructor for the `DataGrid`. By default the page size is **50**, so it will only display 50 records.

Either you use another cosntructor (`DataGrid(int pageSize)`) or you add a `Pager` (i.e. `SimplePager`)